# Delete rows on multiple worksheets using userform 'delete' button

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row, worksheet

I have modified code written by Roy Cox (Thank you for saving me SO much time!) to create a userform to add, modify and delete users' details in an analysis tool I am creating.

It works perfectly when working with user data on a single worksheet. I would like to modify the code so that when a user is added or deleted, it checks each worksheet and modifies the adds or deletes rows accordingly.

This is the code to delete the pupil data on a single sheet:

```
Private Sub cmbDelete_Click()

Dim msgResponse As String    'confirm delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'get user confirmation
msgResponse = MsgBox("This will delete the selected record. Continue?", _
        vbCritical + vbYesNo, "Delete Entry")
Select Case msgResponse    'action dependent on response

Case vbYes
    'c has been selected by Find button on UserForm
    Set c = ActiveCell
        c.EntireRow.Delete    'remove entry by deleting row

'restore form settings
    With Me
        .cmbAmend.Enabled = False    'prevent accidental use
        .cmbDelete.Enabled = False    'prevent accidental use
        .cmbAdd.Enabled = True    'restore use
        'clear form
        Call ClearControls
    End With

Case vbNo
    Exit Sub    'cancelled
End Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I have tried modifying it to delete the user data on each worksheet, as follows:

```
Private Sub cmbDelete_Click()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim msgResponse As String    'confirm delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'get user confirmation
msgResponse = MsgBox("This will delete the selected record. Continue?", _
        vbCritical + vbYesNo, "Delete Entry")
Select Case msgResponse    'action dependent on response

Case vbYes
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With Sh.UsedRange
        'c has been selected by Find button
        Set c = ActiveCell
            c.EntireRow.Delete    'remove entry by deleting row
    Next

'restore form settings
    With Me
        .cmbAmend.Enabled = False    'prevent accidental use
        .cmbDelete.Enabled = False    'prevent accidental use
        .cmbAdd.Enabled = True    'restore use
        'clear form
        Call ClearControls
    End With

Case vbNo
    Exit Sub    'cancelled
End Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

but get a

> 'Next without For' error.

I don't understand why this is happening as I thought that is what I was doing in this section:

```
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
With Sh.UsedRange
    'c has been selected by Find button
    Set c = ActiveCell
        c.EntireRow.Delete    'remove entry by deleting row
Next
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

(I am hoping that once I have solved the deletion problem, I will be able to modify the solution to add rows when adding a new pupil!)

Comment: end with before next

Comment: Thanks for your help Srijan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `End With`:

```
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With Sh.UsedRange
        'c has been selected by Find button
        Set c = ActiveCell
        c.EntireRow.Delete    'remove entry by deleting row
    End With
Next
```

before the `Next`.

---

As a best practice, it is probably a better idea to use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`, because it loops only the Worksheets and avoids the Charts, if they are available.

Comment: Thanks Vityata - I have taken note of this and changed it.

Comment: Such a simple correction! I now have a problem that, when I select the user and click delete, the user and the next 3 rows also get deleted on the first worksheet but nothing gets deleted on the second (test) worksheet. Do you have any thoughts on how to resolve this at all? Thanks.

Comment: @gbra - yup, some errors are simple to solve. Concerning the second error, it is a good idea ask a new question.

Comment: of course that fixed the syntax error but the code is both redundant (`With Sh.UsedRange` reference is never _used_) and logically wrong (setting `Set c = ActiveCell` doesn't change `c` and hence `c.EntireRow.Delete` would keep deleting the same row in the same sheet)